How to decode account data in more readable format?
I am making an API call using Solana JSON RPC API defined below:
{
"method": "getAccountInfo",
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"params": [
"address",
{
"encoding": "base64",
"commitment": "confirmed"
}
],
"id": "id"
}
That returns me data in this format:
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
"context": {
"apiVersion": "1.18.22",
"slot": 286879798
},
"value": {
"data": [
"",
"base64"
],
"executable": false,
"lamports": 2394240,
"owner": "",
"rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
"space": 216
}
},
"id": ""
}
I want to decode the data to be more readable format and decoding the base64 string into binary buffer is as far as I have got. How can I property decode this data to extract the information that I need? I see that the API documentation states that there is a "program:state" in the return which I want to access but I can seem to get it to return back.

The data onchain is serialized. Once you obtain the data buffer with getAccountInfo, you need to deserialize it. You need to know the expected struct, build the struct and then you can deserialize it.
More info here https://solana.com/es/developers/courses/native-onchain-development/deserialize-custom-data-frontend#deserializing-program-data
